# Is it correct to use multi viewsets for a model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which its fields must be filled by both user and admin the key issue is that user need to fill some fields by API request and admin need to fill the others in `Django admin panel`, I dont want user can allow to `POST` data to fill some fields but they would be able to see all feilds in `GET` request.
I think this is possible with different routes and viewset. but as I'm a newbie in Python/Django I'm not sure what is the best practice(s) for this porpuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the serializer. therefore, when the user sends all fields, you just serialize specific fields and validate them, then by overwriting `create` method you can save every field is required.read [serializer document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects)